# cannot find @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do the scrollview and it gave me this error please help

[showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knVQ6.png)

Answer (score -2):

I think you have not got dimens or have been deleted. So delete all the error code and give padding what do you want